# Get a TextReader from a Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I'm trying to read an embedded text file with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);` but it gives me a `Stream`. The embedded resource is a text file so, how can I turn this `Stream` into a `TextReader`?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Comment: Please note that in this assignment, an encoding is used to convert from bytes to characters. By default, the encoding is detected.

Answer (score 20):

A `StreamReader` is a subclass of `TextReader`, so you will be able to do:

```
using(var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
    GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    // Use reader.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to get a StreamReader from it (TextReader is an abstract base class of StreamReader and StringReader). Something like:

```
var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
    GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can read your resource file like this :

```
Assembly resourceAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(resourceFile.FullName);
string[] manifests = resourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

using (ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(
    resourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(manifests[0])))
{
    foreach (IDictionaryEnumerator dict in reader)
    {
        string key = dict.Key as string;
        object val = dict.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `foreach` loop is better than an explicit enumerator.