# Open a resource file with StreamReader?

Tags: c#

This doesnt work:

```
string fileContent = Resource.text;
    StreamReader read = File.OpenText(fileContent);

    string line;
            char[] splitChar = "|".ToCharArray();

            while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] split = line.Split(splitChar);
                string name = split[0];
                string lastname = split[1];

            }

            read.Dispose();
```

How do you open a resource file to get its contents?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it throw an exception? Does it silently fail?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342975/get-a-textreader-from-a-stream/5343005#5343005

Comment: A resource file is typically a binary file. Reading it with a `StreamReader` probably won't give you the information you want. See the answer that @Arnaud F. provided for reading a text resource from a stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
string fileContent = Resource.text;
using (var reader = new StringReader(fileContent))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split('|');
        string name = split[0];
        string lastname = split[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a file called security.file. It is a text file and when I assign Resource.text to fileContent. It's a byte[] and can not be implicitly converted to string

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable fileContent already has all the contents you need.

Answer (score 0):

to read resources, you need a special Stream named "ResourceReader", you can use it like this :

```
string fileContent = "<your resource file>";

using (ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(fileContent))
{
    foreach (IDictionaryEnumerator dict in reader)
    {
        string key = dict.Key as string;
        object val = dict.Value;
    }
}
```